# Does Disciple of Life's extra healing apply to Vampiric Touch?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cleric, warlock

The sorclock I'm building (see cheese elsewhere) will be picking up a level of cleric, probably Life Domain.

It looks like [Vampiric Touch](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Vampiric%20Touch#h-Vampiric%20Touch) would interact with [Disciple of Life](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Cleric#h-Disciple%20of%20Life) to provide extra healing.

Is that correct, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this should work. Disciple of Life says that

> Whenever you use a spell of 1st level or higher 
>   to restore hit points to a creature, the creature regains 
>   additional hit points equal to 2 + the spell’s level.

*Vampiric Touch* is a spell of 1st level or higher, check. You are a creature, so if you use *Vampiric Touch* to restore your hit points, you should get the benefit.

Comment: Woohoo! Double leech!

Comment: Not the leech.  Only the restoration would get affected, not the damage dealt.

Comment: Probably worth clarifying the math here. You roll _Vampiric Touch_ and deal *10 pts of damage.* By default you would heal *5 points of damage*, but instead you heal *10 (5+2+3) points of damage*. If you cast this as a 4th level spell and dealt 10 pts, you would instead heal 11 pts because of the spell's level.

Comment: @Miniman Vampiric Touch has a duration?..Does that still counts as "when ever you use a spell of Lv1 +" that the effects of Disciple of Life still occur?

Comment: @JhayrelleSilver [We have a question about using Disciple of Life with a spell that heals over the duration](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/96622/15469). You asked it, actually.